# 12V battery terminals voltage

Tags: voltage, batteries

In a 12 volt battery, does one terminal have +6volt and the other one -6volt, or does one have +12volt and the other one 0volt, or does one have -12volt and the other 0volt?

A charged plate will attract another plate with the opposite polarity
But if one of the plates is neutral 0Volt and the other one is charged then there will be no attraction. Correct?

So if you connect the battery terminals to capacitative plates, will they attract eachother?

Comment: Gabriel Philips - Hi, Stack Exchange (SE) ([tour]) is different from typical forums, where question topics can change & evolve. On SE that should not happen, as it leads to "chameleon questions" where earlier answers are rendered invalid / incomplete by later changes to the question. You added to the question after receiving an answer, so there are now answers to multiple different versions of the question. Please stop doing that - no further changes to the question should be made now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> does one terminal have +6V and the other one -6V?

Yes.

> does one have +12V and the other one 0V?

Yes.

> does one have -12V and the other 0V?

Yes.

The only truth you know about a 12V battery is that there's a difference of 12V between one terminal and the other.

It's up to you to decide what 0V means in the context of your circuit. If you decide that the negative terminal shall be called "0V", or "ground", then from that moment on, everything connected to the negative terminal shall also  have 0V potential (ground), and anything connected to the positive terminal shall be deemed to be 12V higher in potential, or 0V + 12V = +12V.

if you decide to have some other node in your circuit be "ground", and it later turns out that the the battery negative happens to be 6V lower in potential, then what you have is -6V at the battery's negative terminal, and +6V at its positive terminal.

You get the idea. Everything's relative, there's really no such thing as an "absolute" potential, just what you arbitrarily declare to be a 0V node (ground), and potentials everywhere else are declared/measured relative to that.

Actually, your choice of ground node isn't *that* arbitrary. You choose the node that makes most sense to be called "zero volts". At some point you'll have to explain how your circuit works, or show the schematic to another engineer, or start using algebra to calculate the circuit's behaviour, all of which are much easier if you choose the 0V node wisely.

Sorry, I forgot to answer your other questions, about the charged plates.

If you haven't grokked this already, there's no such thing as an "absolute potential", only potential differences. That is, you can't actually say that "the voltage here is +5V", or "over there it's -10V", unless everybody agrees about where and what zero volts is.

When you "charge" a plate, by pushing charges onto it, you are also expelling charges from the other. All you are doing is raising the potential of one of the plates *relative* to the other. The result is that the plates will have a potential difference between them, and that will indeed cause the plates to attract each other. The plates will experience zero net force only when they have 0V potential *difference* between them.

It makes no sense to talk of the potential of one plate independently of the other. The only meaningful quantity, that you can use to determine how they interact, is the potential *difference* between them. You can declare one plate to have a potential of +1,000V, and the other to be at −2,000V, or you could declare one to be at +10,000V while the other is +7,000V, and nothing would change. The only meaningful value is the difference of 3,000V.

By connecting a pair of capacitive plates across a 12V battery, you are injecting charges onto one plate, and removing them from the other. Once the system has settled, you have a potential difference of 12V between the plates. You don't know (or need to know) what the absolute potential of either plate is, you know only that they are 12V different from each other.

However, you are free to declare that one plate is 0V, so everybody knows what you mean when you say 0V, and subsequently everybody will understand and agree when you tell them that the absolute potential of the other plate is now +12V (or −12V, depending on which one you chose to be zero).

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying, any battery or voltage source produces a difference in electrical potential between its terminals. If you choose a reference point that is one of the points of the battery (for example GND) all the voltages will have a value dependent on that point. Because of this, you can also have a midpoint as your reference and the battery would have its ends at +6V and -6V.

Normally, since batteries only have two terminals, their voltage is the difference between their points (in **this case, yes 12V**). If you add more elements to your circuit, you can get different references and get other voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy4yyQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A charged plate will attract another plate with the opposite polarity
But if one of the plates is neutral 0Volt and the other one is charged then there will be no attraction. Correct?

So if you connect the battery terminals to capacitative plates, will they attract eachother?

Comment: Voltage, is the difference in electric potential **between two points**. On a conductor, a surface charge will experience a force in the presence of an electric field. This force is the average of the discontinuous electric field at the surface charge. I not really sure how the charge is distributed in an alkaline battery. But I assume that there will be positive and negative charges on both sides of the battery.

Comment: FYI, capacitors do not divide voltages at DC. The voltages across VM2 and VM3 will depend on the relative resistances of VM2 and VM3.

Answer (score 1):

> But if one of the plates is neutral 0Volt and the other one is charged then there will be no attraction. Correct?

It is not as simple as that.

Charges create electric fields. Electric fields cause charges *in conductors* to rearrange themselves. That is, conductors in electric fields become *polarized*. Even if a conductor has, overall, a surplus of electrons, it may be polarized so that one side has a surplus of electrons and the other side has a deficit. This can cause two unequally charged conductors, which are charged to the same polarity to attract each other, provided the distance between them is small, where "small" depends on the relative total charge of the system.

See for example: [this article](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/84/6/474/1038200/Regions-of-attraction-between-like-charged)

If one side of a plate capacitor were connected to a Van de Graaff generator, with say 100,000 V relative to *physical* earth, and the other plate of the capacitor were connected to a different Van de Graaff generator, with a voltage 5 V different from the other (i.e. 100,005 V relative to physical earth), the two plates of the capacitor would certainly repel each other.

However, if the plates were at 100 V and 105 V relative to physical earth, they would almost certainly attract each other. It takes a "large" voltage relative to earth to put a sufficiently large net charge on a conductor to cause the kind of effect seen in a [gold-leaf electroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroscope#Gold-leaf_electroscope).

> So if you connect the battery terminals to capacitative plates, will they attract each other?

The plates in a capacitor connected across a 12V battery, provided the battery and capacitor circuit is not connected to something like a Van de Graaff generator, nor been struck by lightning, will definitely attract each other.

Engineering involves knowing what aspects of reality to ignore. In electronics, we ignore the *absolute* net charge in a circuit. This is because most circuits have a total net charge that is too "small" for gold-leaf electroscope type repulsion. When we ignore the absolute net charge in a circuit, we treat "ground" as an arbitrary choice. We can say that one terminal of a battery is at 0V and the other at 12V, or we can say one terminal is at -12V and the other at 0V. Or, we can take any place in our circuit as 0V, and it might happen that with that choice, one terminal of the battery had -6V and the other +6V. These choices, (from the point of view of electronics) are arbitrary, and the models that result from those choices are equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjxY8q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That was a very thorough answer, thank you

Comment: Are you saying that two slightly different positively charged plates of a plane capacitor would attract? The article linked is about charged spheres and in that case it's the nonuniform geometry that explains the origin of the attraction (I seem to recall something on Jackson about a point charge near a charged spheres). But for planar plates?

Comment: Yes. Two plates with differing positive charges will attract each other if they are sufficiently close. The effect is not dependent on the conductors being spherical. The plates will polarize.

Comment: I had a look at Jackson and for the case of a point charge near a same charged spheres, the effect depends on the radius of the sphere and disappears when said radius goes to infinity. But imagine now two infinitely large plates: what breaks the simmetry to localize an opposite sign charge somewhere on the plane? Or are you saying that the entire plane flips sign, under a certain distance?

Comment: Neverind, I had computed the limit in my head without the a^3 term. So, the whole plane of lesser charge would be displaced?

Comment: Yes, infinite plates don't work, because distance terms cancel out. Must be realistic (i.e. non-infimite) so that field falls off with distance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no +6V or -6V because then there is no 0V.
Yes there is +12V and 0V, or yes there is 0V and -12V.

Comment: A charged plate will attract another plate with the opposite polarity
But if one of the plates is neutral 0Volt and the other one is charged then there will be no attraction. Correct?

So if you connect the battery terminals to capacitative plates, will they attract eachother?

Comment: I disagree. You can label the terminals in any way. If you can't label them as +6V and -6V terminals, then you can't label any of the terminals as 0V terminal either for the same reason you can't label any of the terminals as +6V.

Answer (score 0):

Neither battery terminal is at any specified voltage, such as 0V or 12V, as the battery terminals are isolated from any external voltage so they have no reference to any voltage.

There will just be 12V difference between the two battery terminals, and they are floating.

So it is up to you to define the voltages and label them, only if you decide to label one of the terminals as 0V terminal, the other terminal will have a 12V difference from that, so depending on which terminal you chose as 0V terminal, the other either has 12V more positive or 12V more negative than your 0V terminal.

You can freely label the terminals as -6V and +6V terminals if you want, or 1000V and 1012V terminals, when you define the battery in respect to some external reference that makes sense. Just like a 12 foot pole is a 12 foot pole, no matter if you dig it halfway into ground so there's 6 feet under and above ground level, or whether you take the pole to the bottom of the ocean or on top of a mountain.